# Unable to install npm and issue like this Node_Env = debug

Tags: node.js, sass, npm-install, node-sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE77g.png)

The above issue is getting arises while using the npm I command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.